# MessageDigest digest() method

Tags: java, encryption, md5

Shouldn't the digest() method in MessageDigest always give the same hash value for the same input?

I tried this and I am getting different set of hashvalues for the same input everytime

```
md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
System.out.println(md5.digest("stringtodigest".getBytes()));
System.out.println(md5.digest("stringtodigest".getBytes())); 
System.out.println(md5.digest("stringtodigest".getBytes()));
```

Update:  Changed the param to digest() method

Comment: Is there actually a method with the signature `digest(String input)`? Because [I can't see one](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're seeing the results of calling `byte[].toString()` - which isn't showing you the actual hash of the data. You're basically getting a string which shows that you've called `toString` on a byte array (that's the `[B` part) and then the hash returned by `Object.hashCode()` (that's the hex value after the `@`). That hash code doesn't take the *data* in the array into account.

Try

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(md5.digest(byteArrayToDigest)));
```

to see the actual *data*.

EDIT: Quick note about creating an MD5 digest from *string* data - you should always use the same encoding, explicitly, when hashing. For example:

```
byte[] hash = md5.digest(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Note also that md5.digest takes a byte array as input, not a string.

Comment: @JeffFoster: I'm assuming the OP's real code is actually valid :) Will update my example though, thanks.